# SQL Subquery column equals operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a SQL query for user with certain permission `enabled` flag. I know, I can do this:

```
select u.ID, u.Name, 
   (select p.Value 
    from Permissions p 
    where p.UserID = u.ID AND p.Key = 'CanEdit') as IsPermissionEnabled
from Users u
```

But it's not exactly what I need, can I do something like this:

```
select u.ID, u.Name, 
   ((select p.Value 
    from Permissions p 
    where p.UserID = u.ID AND p.Key = 'CanEdit') = 'True') 
   as IsPermissionEnabled
from Users u
```

It didn't work for me. So, how to change my query to make it work?

Comment: what should the expected output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select u.ID, u.Name, case when p.value>0 then 'True' else '' end   
   as IsPermissionEnabled
from Users u
left join permission p on p.UserID = u.ID and p.key='CanEdit'
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely you should just join to the table to get `p.Value`.

Then you can do with it whatever you like:

```
SELECT 
    u.ID, 
    u.Name, 
    p.Value   as IsPermissionEnabled
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Permissions p
  ON p.UserID = u.ID 
  AND p.Key = 'CanEdit';
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you need an explicit `case` statement.  So, you can write the query as:

```
select u.ID, u.Name, 
       (case when (select p.Value 
                   from Permissions p 
                   where p.UserID = u.ID AND p.Key = 'CanEdit'
                  ) = 'True'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as IsPermissionEnabled
from Users u;
```

Comment: This would of course fail if the subquery returned multiple values. It does assume that the `UserID/Key` is the primary key.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson . . . The OP strongly suggests that the subquery returns at most one value, by implying that the first query works.

Answer (score 0):

A join ( inner or left) with a Case can be used to return the desired data with  IsPermissionEnabled. Assuming intent is to treat IsPermissionEnabled as boolean, the case statement can set it to a bit value of 0 or 1 as below.

```
select u.USERID , u.Username, IsPermissionEnabled =  case  p.[Key]  when 'CanEdit' then 1 else 0 end  from [Permissions] p inner join [User] u on u.USERID = p.userid
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it clearer for other readers.